# Run script from another directory in windows command line

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to run a script like this

`../../dirA/dirB/run.bat`

The reason why I do that and not run the script directly is that this exact line above is called from another software and I cannot do it differently.
The software does not support running cmd in different directory, only supports starting cmd and running one command - that's what I do.

The issue is, cmd throws this error:

```
'..' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

One way to work around this is to put another batch script into the software folder - this script then would call another script, in batch i can use

```
call ../../dirA/dirB/run.bat
```

But is there a different way - cleaner?
Is there a way to call `../../dirA/dirB/run.bat` from cmd directly?

I have to mention that I cannot specify an exact path on exact drive - the drive is a clearquest dynamic view, therefore every user can mount it under a different letter, with different name, that is why I need the `..` method.

I only know where it is relative to current directory.

Comment: @ThomasWeller The issue is, the drive is not always the same, not even the name is. 
Netdrive is probably not a good explanation, its a clearquest dynamic view. let me edit the question - I did not include this since I wanted to make the question as exact as possible, sorry about that.

Comment: @ThomasWeller sadly, the same issue. It only runs one more cmd and throws the error in there.

Comment: Ok, in that case I think we need more information. In which directory is cmd or the batch file started? What is the exact command line for starting the batch file? Use Process Monitor or Process Explorer to figure out the working directory.

Comment: The working dir is OK. 

maindir/dirX/dirY is the directory I am in, the dir of the cmd.
maindir/dirA/dirB/run.cmd is the one I need

Comment: `call` seems to work for me: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtEJc.png

Comment: @ThomasWeller It does not for me if I run it directly in cmd, it throws the same error message.

Comment: What exactly does the program run? Does it run `cmd`? Does it run whatever you type? Please look up the exact command line

Comment: You can check it here on page 222 https://www2.lauterbach.com/pdf/ide_ref.pdf . 

The command runs system shell, therefore cmd.exe and then passes the command to it. Therefore I thought that calling the same thing in cmd should be the same behavior - and I still get error from it. 

I can surely work around it with another batch file, I will probably do that and close this question, I was just wondering if there's a better way

Comment: `cmd /c call ../../run.bat`

Comment: @ThomasWeller '..' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. Sadly the same issue.

Comment: Examples 3, 4 and 5 show exactly that.

Comment: The path separator in Windows is a backslash.

Comment: @IInspectable Hi. Sadly, even with backslashes or double backslashes I got the same error message.

Comment: We still have no evidence. I'm voting to close because the question is missing details.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting that this were a solution. Just a slight hint that maybe you shouldn't just start with what is known to be wrong. It's unclear what you hope a double backslash to mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result seems to be - it is not possible when done in cmd directly.
I will get the same result with a workaround - creating another batch file in the directory, then call the script from here.